# rss and atom content type

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, rss, content-type, atom-feed

I have a problem with my feed's content-type:

When I set the `content-type` to `"application/rss+xml"` or `"application/atom+xml"` the **Firefox** will render it current (and displays the default subscribe page), but the **Chrome** renders it as `"text/plain"`. When I change the `content-type` to `"text/xml"` or `"application/xml"` both **Firefox** and **Chrome** render it as a **xml** document (and **Firefox** will not show the Subscribe page).

Have you any idea or suggestion? Which content-type should I use for **rss.xml** and **atom.xml**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MIME type application/rss+xml is [not recognized](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) by the IANA, though some RSS-consuming applications support it anyway.

Because it's not recognized, the only official MIME type to use is text/xml.

Atom feeds do have the official MIME type of application/atom+xml.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the exact type that is specified for that file format. **Chrome** itself doesn't do anything special with `application/rss+xml` or `atom+xml` and then when things such as `registerContentHandler` or web intents land applications will be able to interact with these types.